# White stripes in geom_raster with date variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

Any idea why this plot produces white stripes in the plot:

```
ggplot(test_l,aes(x=date,y=as.factor(IDNum),fill=as.factor(AE)))+
  geom_raster(hjust=0,vjust=0)+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x =element_blank())+
  scale_fill_grey()
```

[image]

Whilst adding as.factor to the data value gives the correct output?

```
ggplot(test_l,aes(x=as.factor(date),y=as.factor(IDNum),fill=as.factor(AE)))+
          geom_raster(hjust=0,vjust=0)+
          theme_classic()+
          theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(),
                axis.text.y=element_blank(),
                axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
                panel.grid.major.x =element_blank())+
          scale_fill_grey()
```

[image]

I checked whether I have any missing date values:

```
> identical((test_l %>% group_by(date) %>% summarize())$date,seq(ymd("2004-01-15"),ymd("2014-12-15"),by='1 month'))
[1] TRUE
```

Moreover, there are assigned values to all the date values:

```
> table(test_l$AE)

  A02   P01   R01    F02  G01   X09    X11  X12   X14   X16  NADA  <NA>   Sum 
   44   116   140    29   101    57     4    83   113   150 12661     0 13498 
> length(test_l$date)
[1] 13498
```

New edit. Minimal reproducible data:

```
> dput(test_l)
structure(list(IDNum = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("2917529", "4431719"), class = "factor"), date = structure(c(12432, 
12463, 12492, 12523, 12553, 12584, 12614, 12645, 12676, 12706, 
12737, 12767, 12798, 12829, 12857, 12888, 12918, 12949, 12979, 
13010, 13041, 13071, 13102, 13132, 13163, 13194, 13222, 13253, 
13283, 13314, 13344, 13375, 13406, 13436, 13467, 13497, 13528, 
13559, 13587, 13618, 13648, 13679, 13709, 13740, 13771, 13801, 
13832, 13862, 13893, 13924, 13953, 13984, 14014, 14045, 14075, 
14106, 14137, 14167, 14198, 14228, 14259, 14290, 14318, 14349, 
14379, 14410, 14440, 14471, 14502, 14532, 14563, 14593, 14624, 
14655, 14683, 14714, 14744, 14775, 14805, 14836, 14867, 14897, 
14928, 14958, 14989, 15020, 15048, 15079, 15109, 15140, 15170, 
15201, 15232, 15262, 15293, 15323, 15354, 15385, 15414, 15445, 
15475, 15506, 15536, 15567, 15598, 15628, 15659, 15689, 15720, 
15751, 15779, 15810, 15840, 15871, 15901, 15932, 15963, 15993, 
16024, 16054, 16085, 16116, 16144, 16175, 16205, 16236, 16266, 
16297, 16328, 16358, 16389, 16419, 12432, 12463, 12492, 12523, 
12553, 12584, 12614, 12645, 12676, 12706, 12737, 12767, 12798, 
12829, 12857, 12888, 12918, 12949, 12979, 13010, 13041, 13071, 
13102, 13132, 13163, 13194, 13222, 13253, 13283, 13314, 13344, 
13375, 13406, 13436, 13467, 13497, 13528, 13559, 13587, 13618, 
13648, 13679, 13709, 13740, 13771, 13801, 13832, 13862, 13893, 
13924, 13953, 13984, 14014, 14045, 14075, 14106, 14137, 14167, 
14198, 14228, 14259, 14290, 14318, 14349, 14379, 14410, 14440, 
14471, 14502, 14532, 14563, 14593, 14624, 14655, 14683, 14714, 
14744, 14775, 14805, 14836, 14867, 14897, 14928, 14958, 14989, 
15020, 15048, 15079, 15109, 15140, 15170, 15201, 15232, 15262, 
15293, 15323, 15354, 15385, 15414, 15445, 15475, 15506, 15536, 
15567, 15598, 15628, 15659, 15689, 15720, 15751, 15779, 15810, 
15840, 15871, 15901, 15932, 15963, 15993, 16024, 16054, 16085, 
16116, 16144, 16175, 16205, 16236, 16266, 16297, 16328, 16358, 
16389, 16419), class = "Date"), AE = structure(c(11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 1L, 11L, 4L, 11L, 
4L, 11L, 11L, 4L, 5L, 11L, 11L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 11L, 11L, 4L, 
11L, 5L, 11L, 7L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 4L, 11L, 11L, 1L, 11L, 
11L, 1L, 11L, 1L, 11L, 11L, 1L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 1L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 1L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 8L, 3L, 10L, 8L, 8L, 11L, 9L, 8L, 11L, 
11L, 8L, 1L, 8L, 11L, 11L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 8L), .Label = c("AF01", 
"AF01, AX12", "AF01, AX16", "AF02", "AF02, AX09", "AX09", "AX09, AF02", 
"AX12", "AX12, AF01", "AX16", "NADA"), class = "factor")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -264L), .Names = c("IDNum", 
"date", "AE"))
```

Comment: fyi: I think you pasted twice the code with as.factor

Comment: it probably has to do with how R understands your x axis. 

When it is not explicitly a factor, R understands it as a continuous variable and expect some y data for each value of x. But you don't have a y value for all the values of x, hence the white lines

Comment: Can you `dput` your data so we can try to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I´ve pasted dput data from two IDs reproducing the stripe.

Answer (score 1):

Simulating the impact of using factor on the x axis or not:

In my dataset, there is no data for 2013:

```
df = data.frame(year=c(2010,2011,2012,2014,2015),value=c(10,11,12,14,15))
```

Using factor(), R doesn't include 2013

```
ggplot(df,aes(factor(year),value))+geom_bar(stat="identity")+theme_classic()+
  theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x =element_blank())+
  scale_fill_grey()
```

[image]

Without factor(), R adds 2013 to the x axis:

```
ggplot(df,aes((year),value))+geom_bar(stat="identity")+theme_classic()+
  theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x =element_blank())+
  scale_fill_grey()
```

[image]

And you end up having empty an space in your plot

Comment: I dont think that explains the white stripes. See my edit.

Comment: oh, ok, then I don't know, sorry. did you try using geom_area instead of geom_raster ?

Comment: hey @Misha 

I took another look. the problem seem to appear only when using months. 

It creates discontinuity, example:

as.numeric(as.Date(c("2004-02-15","2004-03-15")))
gives: 12463 12492

and you don't have any Y value for the X between 12463 and 12492

geom_raster seem to have trouble with this discontinuity. Your solution with factor(), given that you have no missing values, seems like a safe option, even if you have to overwrite the x axis labels and ticks...

Comment: Appreciate your efforts. I found a couple of other SO questions also hinting at a problem with geom_raster and dates. Maybe it should be filed on github?

Comment: yup, it makes sense to me to report it. :)